# Adding reference to a DLL doesnt copy all the dependent DLLs in the bin folder in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

I have following scenario, Project A is refering A1 and A2 DLLs. Proj A is an library project, containing some common Data releted functionality, which can be used across all the application. Project B in solution X and the Project C in solution Y are dependent on Project A for using its Data related functionality. Now I have following options.

Option 1:

Add project A in Both the solutions X and Y and let the projects B and C in the respective solutions add project A as an "project Reference", this will copy A.dll, A1.dll and A2.dll in the bin folder of project B and C automatically.

Pros:

1. If I change anything in Proj A, it will get reflected automatically in Proj B and C.
2. As I mentioned, it will copy not only A.dll but A1.dll and A2.dll in the bin folder of Proj B and Proj C.

Cons:

1. If i change the location of Proj A, then i need to fix this in Both the solution and need to build all the solutions which are using Proj A as an project Reference.

Option 2:

Create a seperate central solution which include all the common library project. Create a project CommonLib add to that all the library projects as an project Reference, so that the CommonLib is referencing Proj A as an project reference. This will copy A.dll , A1.dll and A2.dll in the bin folder of CommonLib project. Now project B and C in solution X and Y need to refer the A.dll from the bin folder of project CommonLib.

Pros:

1. Change in location of proj A will not impact fixing Sol X and Y, as you need to fix at only one single place that is the CommnLib solution.

Cons:

1. If you refer A.dll from the commonlib bin folder, in the proj B, then it does not automatically copy A1.dll and A2.dll in the bin folder of proj B. So you never come to know what are all DLLs proj A is dependent on.

Why doesnt when i refer A.dll from the bin folder of CommonLib project, doesnt include A1.dll and A2.dll ? Any solution for this.

[Note: I dont want to use GAC]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option 1 is the best option 2 is not best